# XCode Header Search Paths for global struct

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I created a struct called PointInt that is simply two integers (like CGPoint but with ints) and I want it to be a global struct just like CGPoint. I also created a category for NSValue for this.

I've looked all over the Internet and it seems that Build Settings -> Header Search Paths is the way to go. However, I have no idea what values to put into it. I've tried `$(PROJECT_DIR)/PointInt/**` and a bunch of similar strings but the compiler does not recognize it. How do I `#import` a .h file for the struct, then another .h and a .m for the category? And is there anything else that has to be done?

Comment: assuming the `PointInt.h` and `NSValue+PointInt.h` are both in your project, you can just `#import` them without problem.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough. I meant that there should be a way to have those files in every other file without having to type `#import` every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the header file with the struct to your prefix header. One will have been automatically created for you when you created the project called `[project]-Prefix.pch` in the "Supporting Files" directory.

Add it in between `#ifdef __OBJC__` and `#endif`.

It will then be available throughout your project.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Is this the normal way to include global structs like this?
But if those #imports in that block are global and the block includes `Foundation` and `UIKit`, why do all `ViewControllers` have those imported? Isn't that redundant?

Comment: Yes, that's the normal way. All classes within your project will have all of those imports which is a convenience because you'll use them often. The header files only contain definitions which won't affect the compiled code if unused so you don't need to worry about redundancy but it's good practice to prefix your struct with a few capital letters (such as your initials or the initials of the project) to reduce the risk of name conflicts.

Comment: You can also use the prefix header to add commonly used header files such as `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` or for vendor code you're using

Comment: Ah. And what about the second question about why lots of files `#import` `Foundation` and `UIKit` even though they're already globally imported?

Comment: Yes, this is totally redundant but not harmful as `#import` will only ever run once (unlike the old c style `#include` which you had to be careful not to double up on).